# Using ffmpeg results in undesirable motion blur

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, video-processing, video-encoding

I am trying to convert a video with the best quality possible. The problem is, no matter which command arguments I use, a motion blur appears (the first image is converted, the second is the original):

[image: Converted] [image: Original]

The ffprobe's output of the original video:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2-1ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-3ubuntu1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'input.ts':
Duration: 00:00:30.24, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 26265 kb/s
Program 1
    Metadata:
    service_name    : Service01
    service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](ita): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s (clean effects)
```

I've tried different combinations of the following arguments:

```
ffmpeg \
-i input.ts \
-c:v libx264 \
-preset veryslow \
-qp 0 \
-minrate 25165824 \
-b:v 25165824 \
-r 25 \
-s 1920x1080 \
-aspect 16:9 \
-g 25 \
-crf 7 \
output.ts
```

None of these settings helped. Please, could you tell me how to remove this motion blur?

**EDIT:** to be more specific, I leave a [link to a shorten video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mkswB6qUQP4vs2eaYzyIlgCzfuYZ0H7B/view?usp=sharing) (~10 seconds). If you manage to convert it to hls (h.264 & .m3u8) without motion blur and with preserving the overall quality, it will be equivalent to the answer.

Comment: I've noticed that this depends on the source file. With some source files everything is OK, while with others ffmpeg reduces video quality, leaving motion blur in my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is related to interlacing so you need to **de-interlace** the video.

Looking at FFprobe's output of `yuv420p(tv, top first)`, this is a clue that your video (per frame) is indeed interlaced and with top-field first then bottom-field second.

Possible **solution**:

a) *try using [**BWdif**](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#bwdif)*:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -vf bwdif -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 19 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.ts
```

b) *try using [**W3Fdif**](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#w3fdif)*:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -vf setfield=tff,w3fdif -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 19 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output2.ts
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep your clip interlaced. Usually deinterlacing introduces blur. There are some deinterlacers using motion prediction that create good results for high motion footage.

I tried: `ffmpeg -i input.ts -c:v libx264 -crf 7 -x264opts tff=1 output.ts` giving me reasonable results.